# django-paypal ipn works fine but signal is not received

Tags: django, django-paypal

I have this code at the end of my models.py file

```
from paypal.standard.ipn.signals import payment_was_successful

def confirm_payment(sender, **kwargs):
    # it's important to check that the product exists
    logging.debug('** CONFIRMED PAYMENT ***') #never reached this point
    try:
        bfeat = BuyingFeature.objects.get(slug=sender.item_number)
    except BuyingFeature.DoesNotExist:
        return
    # And that someone didn't tamper with the price
    if int(bfeat.price) != int(sender.mc_gross):
        return
    # Check to see if it's an existing customer
    try:
        customer = User.objects.get(email=sender.payer_email)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        customer = User.objects.create(
            email=sender.payer_email,
            first_name=sender.first_name,
            last_name=sender.last_name
        )
    # Add a new order
    CustomerOrder.objects.create(customer=customer, feature=bfeat, quantity=1, paypal_email=sender.payer_email, invoice=sender.invoice, remarks='')

payment_was_successful.connect(confirm_payment)
```

The whole process runs ok. Payment is complete. return_url and cancel_url work fine. notify_url was tested from the paypal sandbox's test tools and works ok. However, signal is never received.

Signal code is placed at the end of the models.py and django-paypal code is placed inside my project's directory.

(code was 'stolen' from [here](http://webcloud.se/log/Implementing-PayPal-in-Django/))

I must be doing something completely wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you resolve this?  Am travelling the same road and everything works except the signals.  So frustrating!

Comment: no, i didn't. I have managed to find a workaround for this. What I did was to modify paypal/standard/ipn/views.py and add my code to process each order (just after ipn_obj.save()) http://dpaste.com/563990/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django-paypal there are two signals for basic transactions:

```
payment_was_successful
payment_was_flagged
```

You must handle both signals.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem - and having chased around a few similar questions have found a resolution for my specific case. I mention it here in case anyone else is hitting this wall.

I've not researched it thoroughly, but it looks as though it's highly dependent on which version/repository you source your copy of django-paypal from. Specifically, the version I downloaded wasn't updated to accommodate the {% csrf_token %} idiom. To get this to work, I had to add the @csrf_exempt decorator to two views:

1. the ipn view in paypal.standard.views
2. the view loaded by the return url in my django paypal dictionary (... this one flags a highly accurate error if you have debug on).

Answer (score 0):

Is `django-paypal` there in the `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

I don't see any other reason why the signal wouldn't be fired, otherwise.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I have placed this line `'paypal.standard.ipn'` in my settings.py. I also tried `my_project.paypal.standard.ipn'` because paypal is located inside my project's folder. And this is what I have in my urls.py: `(r'^hard/guess/$', include('paypal.standard.ipn.urls')),`. Concerning settings.py, should paypal app comes before or after the line with my project app?

Comment: Hi, I also noticed that `paypal_ipn` table is receiving data (i.e.  `ipn_obj.save()` in `standard.ipn.views.py`, works). Only that the field `flag_info` is getting a "Invalid payment_status. (Pending)" text. So, if `standard.ipn.views.py` is working then installed_apps and urls.py configuration is fine. So, the error must be somewhere else. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: and something else. How can I be sure that "payment_was_successful" signal is received and not some other signal?

Comment: I noticed in the IPN history (in paypal) that the request attribute `payment_status` is `Pending`. Does this mean anything?